# Update_attribute not working in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have code in model level to update attribute to TeacherPayslip.

TeacherPayslip.rb (Model)

```
def net_salary   
    @teacher_id = self.id
    @da  =  (self.basic * self.da)/100 
    @hra = (self.basic * self.hra)/100 
    @gs  = @da + @hra + self.basic
    @pf =  (@gs * self.pf)/100
    @netsalary = @gs - @pf + self.special_allowance + self.bonus

    @a = TeacherPayslip.find(@teacher_id)
    #raise @a.inspect

    raise @a.update_attribute('net_salary',@netsalary).inspect
   end
```

Here, when I raise @netsalary shows like 9789. But after updating(@a.update_attribute('net_salary',@netsalary) net_salary shows true value. instead of 9789.

Comment: `update_attribute` method returns true or false only not the value itself. Is that the issuse?

Comment: It shows true instead of the value

Answer (score -1):

`update_attribute` return a boolean (`true` or `false`). Beside, using `update_attribute` instead of `update_attributes` will cause the callbacks to not be fired.

You should use:

```
@a.update_attributes(net_salary: @netsalary)
@a.net_salary # will hold the new value
```

Comment: @Pierre-Louis Gottfrois actually `update_attribute` fires callbacks, but it doesn't run validations.

Comment: @MarekLipka true, then it won't run validation callbacks ;)